# script makes 2 main menus pop up when run at the start, as opposed to the one main menu that it is meant to send

Tags: python, function

```
def mainmenu():
    print ("Welcome to the main menu!")
    print ("1 = Play a Game")
    mmchoice = input ("Choice:")
    return mmchoice

def gamemenu():
    print ("Welcome to the game menu!")
    print ("1 = Back")
    print ("2 = Rock Paper Scissors")
    gmchoice = input ("Choice:")
    return gmchoice

def mainmenuchoices():
    choice = mainmenu()
    if choice == "1":
        gamemenu()

mainmenu()
mainmenuchoices()
```

when you enter one to play a game on the first main menu, another one just pops up, but after choosing an option on the second main menu that shows, it follows the code and goes to the game menu

```
Welcome to the main menu!
1 = Play a Game
Choice:1
Welcome to the main menu!
1 = Play a Game
Choice:1
Welcome to the game menu!
1 = Back
2 = Rock Paper Scissors
Choice:
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `mainmenu()` directly because it is already called in `mainmenuchoices()`. Delete it and it will solve your problem.

```
def mainmenu():
    print ("Welcome to the main menu!")
    print ("1 = Play a Game")
    mmchoice = input ("Choice:")
    return mmchoice

def gamemenu():
    print ("Welcome to the game menu!")
    print ("1 = Back")
    print ("2 = Rock Paper Scissors")
    gmchoice = input ("Choice:")
    return gmchoice

def mainmenuchoices():
    choice = mainmenu()
    if choice == "1":
        gamemenu()

mainmenu()  # DELETE THIS LINE
mainmenuchoices()
```